# Inventory design database with colors and sizes

Tags: php, database, database-design, inventory

I'm planning on making a inventory database design to keep track of what we have in our shop. I'm thinking of storing an array in the database with all sizes and colors like:

```
array('S-groen' => 6,'M-groen' => 0,'L-groen' => 2,'S-zwart' => 9,'M-zwart' => 0,'L-zwart' => 3);
```

Where S is the size, and groen is the color.

But is it good practice to do it like this, or is there a better way?

So my database will be: **ID - product_id - aantal**. In aantal will be the array.

Comment: really depends on what type of database you are going to use. SQL or noSQL based

Comment: You will want a table of products, a table of sizes, a table of colours. then a table that lists a product a size and a colour for that size. I hope that makes sense. you can email me from my profile email if you need more details.

Comment: I guess we can try. Its kind of a lot of text to put though. You need a products table which lists the attributes of your products, name, sku, item #, cost, sell etc

Comment: @LuckyBurger it depends how normalised the datamodel needs to be. A single char size column would probably be more performant and efficient than a whole new table with a bunch of joins in almost every query.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't store multiple values in one column in a relational database - it's generally considered bad practice.

It would be better to have two tables, one with a product name and product ID, and another for variations (having columns variation_id, product_id, size, colour, quantity). The product_id column in the variation table will be a foreign key to the product table.

Comment: variation_id is A.I. right? But won't i get ALOT of records in that table for only one product? Lets say i got 5 sizes and 5 colors, meaning i need to have 25 records in that database for one product?

Comment: variation_id will be a primary key, auto_increment is probably a good idea for it. And yes, that table could have many, many more rows than your product table.

Comment: And that's perfectly ok, to have that many rows? Could not hurt speed or crash or something?

Comment: If it's properly indexed, it shouldn't be a problem. In fact, it should be much faster (both in development time, and at runtime) to do a lot of stuff you're probably going to want to do later.

Comment: If you ever want to show a list of distinct colours or distinct sizes, then these columns should be normalized out into code tables for these attributes.  The variation table, which in many inventory databases would be called a SKU, should be an intersection between product and all of these variations.  Properly normalized databases perform perfectly well in relational database systems like MySQL.

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, don't make an array. Arrays are difficult to read, difficult to process, and difficult to query.

Instead, make a table of colors and a table of sizes.

The size table probably has just a size ID and a size description. The ID could be an integer with an autoincrement, so like 1=small, 2=medium, 3=large, whatever your sizes are. As sizes are routinely identified by short abbreviations, you could use the abbreviation as the primary key: 'S'=small, 'M'=medium, etc. Primary keys should be short, but typical size abbreviations are rarely longer than 4 characters -- XXXL --- which is the same size or smaller than an integer on most database engines (integers typically being 4 or 8 bytes).

Similarly, the color table relates a color ID to a color name. Again, the ID could be an integer: 1=red, 2=green, 3=orange, etc. Or you could make up short abbreviations.

Now let's ignore this issue for a moment and take a step back.

You should have a product table that has various information about the product, like description, manufacturer, price, inventory systems I've worked on always have a ton of things like product category, shipping weight, codes for accounting, whatever. In some inventory systems, you then just store the quantity on hand of each item in the product record. That is, if you have 20 widgets in stock, then in the widget record you have a field for "quantity" and you store the number 20. In other inventory systems, there is a record for each item in inventory, that is, there is an additional "inventory" or "stock item" table with one record for each item, and if you have 20 in stock, then you have 20 records.

If you have stock item records, you MIGHT add size and color fields -- foreign keys to the size and color tables -- to the stock item record. That would be a good answer if there was no additional information associated with a size and color combination.

But I'd guess that you have bar codes on your products, and at least the way it's done here in the U.S., you have a different bar code for each size and color combination. So if you put the size and color in a stock item record, you'd have to repeat the bar code in every stock item record. Duplicate data = bad. Maybe you have other data associated with a size and color.

Better is to, as stwalkerster says, create a "product variations" record. Then this record would have a pointer to the product record, a pointer to the size record, and a pointer to the color record. It would also have the bar code value and any other common data. Then a stock item record would point to a product variations record rather than a product record. That is, you would have 3 levels: product, each product has many variations, each variation has many stock items.

If you don't need individual stock item records, then you can just store the quantity in the product variation record.

You might possibly put the size and color information in the product record and avoid needing two levels. But this would almost certainly create a LOT of duplicate data. I'd guess that if you have, say, a certain style shirt that is available in various sizes and colors, that that shirt must at the very least have a description, "Oxford men's dress shirt with button down color" or whatever. You don't want to have to repeat that description for each different size and color. Not only is that a lot of wasted space on the hard drive, but now you have to worry about a user typing it slightly differently, and then you can't be sure if "Oxford men's dress shirt with button down color" is the same as "Dress shirt, Oxford, men's" or not, etc. You probably also have accounting codes, etc, associated with each product that would be repeated.

You question whether having a separate record for each such variation would not take up a lot of disk space and slow down the system.

But think about it: it would actually take a little LESS space for your stock item table. Instead of having a pointer to the product record and also an index into the size/color array, you would have a single point to the product variations record. One less field.

Sure, you'd have this additional table, the product variations table. But it would have about the same amount of data as your size/color array. I'm not sure if you were thinking that the size/color array is in the database or hard-coded in the program, but either way, that data has to exist SOMEWHERE.

Having a product variations table should eliminate some redundant data. Like I mentioned earlier, the bar code for the variation would then be stored once. With a size/color array, you would presumably have to store the bar code separately and redundantly for each item with that size and color. I don't know your requirements, but there is probably other data associated with a size and color combination that would also have to be repeated.

The only penalty I see here is that you would have many queries that would have to do an extra join. Instead of select whatever from stock_item join product you would have select whatever from stock_item join product_variation join product. But that shouldn't be a big deal if the tables are properly indexed, and by eliminating redundant date, each record is shorter, so they take fewer blocks on disk, which should mitigate the penalty. (In some cases it might actually be faster.)

Comment: Wow what a story. I think i'm gonna go with 2 tables. Product tables and inventory stock table. Because now i have color in the products table as comma seperate like: S,M,L,XL,XXL,XXXL. So i don't really know how i can fix that with another table. You will get alot of records in the product table for each record then...

Comment: If the products table has this comma-separated list, then how do you know the size of any given item in the stock table? Do you repeat the size there? If so, then why also have it in the product table? And in general, comma separated lists are bad news. How would you query on this? Like is you want to know all the products available in large, how would you write that query? You can't size WHERE SIZE='L' because the size might be 'S,L'. You can't say WHERE SIZE LIKE '%L%' because that would also pick up the XLs, XXLs, etc. You can't size SIZE LIKE ',L,' because L might be the first or the last.

Comment: I'm thinking of deleting the sizes/colors like that, and insert them into the new database together with stock. So i can get everything from the new table.